# How to avoid getting error missing expression

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting error something like

```
ORA-00936: missing expression


SELECT * FROM( 
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    ata.ATAID AS ataId,
                    ata.AtaNumber AS ataNumber,
                    ata.Name AS ataName,
                    ata.StartDate,
                    ata.DueDate as EndDate,
                    ata.financeId,
                    ata.PaymentType,
                    NULL AS lastAtaId
                FROM
                    ata
                INNER JOIN
                    weekly_report wr
                ON
                    wr.ataId = ata.ATAID
                INNER JOIN
                    ata_articles aa
                ON
                    aa.wrId = wr.id
                WHERE
                    ata.Ata = 1
                AND
                    ata.Type = 1
                AND
                    ((wr.status = 2 OR wr.status = 5) OR 
                    ((SELECT a.PaymentType FROM ata a WHERE a.ParentAta = ata.ATAID ORDER BY a.AtaNumber DESC) = 2 AND ata.Status = 2))
                AND
                    ata.ProjectID = 137
                AND 
                    ( ata.PaymentType = 1 OR ata.PaymentType = 4)

               UNION 
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    ata.ATAID AS ataId,
                    ata.AtaNumber AS ataNumber,
                    ata.Name AS ataName,
                    ata.StartDate,
                    ata.DueDate as EndDate,
                    ata.financeId,
                    ata.PaymentType,
                    (SELECT a.ATAID FROM ata a WHERE a.ParentAta = ata.ATAID ORDER BY a.AtaNumber DESC) AS lastAtaId                    
                    FROM 
                        ata
                    LEFT JOIN invoice_articles ia
                    
                    ON ata.ATAID=ia.AtaId
                    
                    WHERE 
                        Ata = 1
                    AND
                        Type = 1
                    AND
                        ( PaymentType = 2 OR PaymentType = 3 ) 
                    AND 
                        (Status = 2 OR Status = 5)
                    AND 
                        ProjectID = 137
                UNION 
                SELECT DISTINCT 
                        ata.ATAID AS ataId,
                        ata.AtaNumber AS ataNumber,
                        ata.Name AS ataName,
                        ata.StartDate,
                        ata.DueDate as EndDate,
                        ata.financeId,
                        ata.PaymentType,
                        null AS lastAtaId
                        
                        FROM 
                            ata
                        LEFT JOIN invoice_articles ia
                        
                        ON ata.ATAID=ia.AtaId
                        
                        WHERE 
                            Ata = 1
                        AND
                            Type = 1
                        AND
                            becomeFastFromOtherType = 1
                        AND 
                            (Status = 2 OR Status = 5)
                        AND 
                            ProjectID = 137)  a
                        GROUP BY a.ataId
                        ORDER BY CAST(a.ataNumber AS SIGNED)
```

As far as I run this query I get point that error comes in this line of code (First Select)

```
((SELECT a.PaymentType FROM ata a WHERE a.ParentAta = ata.ATAID ORDER BY a.AtaNumber DESC) = 2 AND ata.Status = 2))
```

I test all three SELECT statment separetly something like this

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
                    ata.ATAID AS ataId,
                    ata.AtaNumber AS ataNumber,
                    ata.Name AS ataName,
                    ata.StartDate,
                    ata.DueDate as EndDate,
                    ata.financeId,
                    ata.PaymentType,
                    NULL AS lastAtaId
                FROM
                    ata
                INNER JOIN
                    weekly_report wr
                ON
                    wr.ataId = ata.ATAID
                INNER JOIN
                    ata_articles aa
                ON
                    aa.wrId = wr.id
                WHERE
                    ata.Ata = 1
                AND
                    ata.Type = 1
                AND
                    (wr.status = 2 OR wr.status = 5) 
                    /*OR 
                    ((SELECT a.PaymentType FROM ata a WHERE a.ParentAta = ata.ATAID ORDER BY a.AtaNumber DESC) = 2 AND ata.Status = 2))*/
                AND
                    ata.ProjectID = 137
                AND 
                    ( ata.PaymentType = 1 OR ata.PaymentType = 4)
```

And Second SELECT statment

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
                    ata.ATAID AS ataId,
                    ata.AtaNumber AS ataNumber,
                    ata.Name AS ataName,
                    ata.StartDate,
                    ata.DueDate as EndDate,
                    ata.financeId,
                    ata.PaymentType
                    --(SELECT a.ATAID FROM ata a WHERE a.ParentAta = ata.ATAID ORDER BY a.AtaNumber DESC) AS lastAtaId                    
                    FROM 
                        ata
                    LEFT JOIN invoice_articles ia
                    
                    ON ata.ATAID=ia.AtaId
                    
                    WHERE 
                        Ata = 1
                    AND
                        Type = 1
                    AND
                        ( PaymentType = 2 OR PaymentType = 3 ) 
                    AND 
                        (Status = 2 OR Status = 5)
                    AND 
                        ProjectID = 137
```

And thirth SELECT statment

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
                ata.ATAID AS ataId,
                ata.AtaNumber AS ataNumber,
                ata.Name AS ataName,
                ata.StartDate,
                ata.DueDate as EndDate,
                ata.financeId,
                ata.PaymentType,
                null AS lastAtaId
                
                FROM 
                    ata
                LEFT JOIN invoice_articles ia
                
                ON ata.ATAID=ia.AtaId
                
                WHERE 
                    Ata = 1
                AND
                    Type = 1
                AND
                    becomeFastFromOtherType = 1
                AND 
                    (Status = 2 OR Status = 5)
                AND 
                    ProjectID = 137  
               -- GROUP BY a.ataId
               -- ORDER BY CAST(a.ataNumber AS SIGNED)
```

All lines of code which is commented it means that this line of code throw me error message.
I was watching a error a couple of minutes but I don't understand what is wrong ? Why I get error ?

Comment: check how many records that query returs `SELECT a.ATAID FROM ata a WHERE a.ParentAta = ata.ATAID ORDER BY a.AtaNumber DESC`

Comment: Nothing return. ORA-00904: "ATA"."ATAID": invalid identifier
Most propably this SELECT needs to be rewritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *all* the subquery expressions

```
(SELECT a.PaymentType FROM ata a WHERE a.ParentAta = ata.ATAID ORDER BY a.AtaNumber DESC) = 2
```

Remove the `ORDER BY` clause

```
(SELECT a.PaymentType FROM ata a WHERE a.ParentAta = ata.ATAID) = 2
```

The subquery is expected to return maximal one row (otherwise you get *a runtime error*), so the `ORDER BY`clause is not *required* and apparently also **not syntactically supported**